# Square matrices such that $X^T MX = 0$ for all $X$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

My goal is to study the set of matrices $R = \{M \in \mathcal{M}_n (\mathbb{R}):\forall X \in \mathbb{R}^n,  X^T MX = 0 \}$ I've determined that these matrices form a group under addition. However I'd like to prove that if $M\in R$ then $ M^T = M^{-1}$ (non including zero obviously), but haven't had any luck so far. Pictorially it's obvious that these matrices act as rotations, albeit rather strong ones.

Comment: In fact, $M$ is in $R$ if and only if $M^T=-M$, which is to say that $M$ is skew symmetric. These matrices are not necessarily rotations, but any rotations must be $90^\circ$ rotations.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  $M^T = -M$ is the end goal, but I really couldn't get there. Do you have a hint?

Comment: To show that $M$ must be skew symmetric, try plugging in $X$’s for which most of the entries are zero and see what this tells you about the entries of $M$.

Comment: Try to develop with indices the condition $X^tMX=0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I got it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different suggestion:

Show that $R$ is closed under taking transposes. Every square matrix $M$ can be written as the decomposition: $$M = \frac{M + M^T}{2} + \frac{M - M^T}{2}$$ as a sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric matrix. Show that the symmetric part,  $N = \frac{M + M^T}{2} = 0$.

This can be done by using the Spectral Theorem to diagonalize it over the real numbers and using $M, M^T \in R$ so $N \in R$.

Or by showing that for every choice of vectors $X, Y$, $X^TMY = 0$, by inspecting $(X+Y)^TN(X+Y)$.

Comment: I really like this answer. To double check, N is symmetric so by the ST it admits an diagonalization over $\mathbb{R}$ where the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues. Now if we assume one of the eigenvalues of $N$ is non zero, we get a contradiction since $N\in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore the diagonal matrix is the zero matrix and $N$ is the zero matrix. Correct?

Comment: Yup. since $N$ is self-adjoint and $X$ is an eigenvector (which exists in $\mathbb{R}^n$) with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $X^TNX = \lambda$.